# toggleClass on click container and remove same class on other containers

Tags: jquery

Right now I can click a title and it toggles the class on all containers. What I need it to do is also toggle the class when I click the title again.

Can anyone help out?

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('open');
  $(this).parents('.container').toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.open .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for demo you can use `<>` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the parent Container when using `removeClass()`

```
$('.title').click(function() {
  //Get the reference of parent container
  var parentContainer = $(this).parents('.container');

  //Remove open class except from parentContainer
  $('.container').not(parentContainer).removeClass('open');

  //Toggle class on parentContainer
  parentContainer.toggleClass("open");
});
```

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  var parentContainer = $(this).parents('.container');
  $('.container').not(parentContainer).removeClass('open');
  parentContainer.toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.open .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use .not(this) in jquery please check my snippet please

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
  $('.container').not(this).removeClass('open');
  $(this).parents('.container').toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.open .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content goes here 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers, especially in hidden snippets, try to explain what you have done.

Comment: you can use .not(this) in jquery please add and check